# add image to JPanel in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

i am new to java swing, and i am using now NetBeant for building the GUI using the drag and drop designer built in NetBeans. the problem i am facing now is, i have the below posted code and it was written in Eclipse, and as you see
I have a class that extends JPanel and I am adding an image captured from the WEB_CAM to that JPanel.now since i switched to NetBeans, I created the JFrame, JPanel, JButtons using the designer, and in the code i am writing in NetBeans, i do not
know how to add the captured image to the JPanel.

in eclipse I created the below posted code in another class, but in NetBeans every thing is generated automatically and i have to do the same work i did in eclipse. i do not know how to add an image to JPanel in NetBeans.

**JPanel inEclipse**

```
class FacePanel extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage image;
int count = 0;

public FacePanel() {
    super();
}

public void setFace (BufferedImage img) {
    this.image = img;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (this.image == null) {
        System.out.println("image is null");
        return;
    }

    g.drawImage(this.image, 10, 10, this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight(), null);
    g.setFont(new Font("arial", 2, 20));
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("processing frame by frame [ frame: " + ( count++) +  " ]", 150, 150);
}

}
```

**Code in NetBeans**

```
    private void initComponents() {

    jpanel1_Preview = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    btn_Play = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btn_Pause = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btn_Capture = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jpanel1_Preview.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Cam_Preview"));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jpanel1_PreviewLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jpanel1_Preview);
    jpanel1_Preview.setLayout(jpanel1_PreviewLayout);
    jpanel1_PreviewLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jpanel1_PreviewLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jpanel1_PreviewLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        jpanel1_PreviewLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 225, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    btn_Play.setText("play");
    btn_Play.setSelected(true);

    btn_Pause.setText("pause");
    btn_Pause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btn_PauseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btn_Capture.setText("capture");
    btn_Capture.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btn_CaptureActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So long as the `FacePanel` is within the Netbeans Projects classpath (you may need to do a clean and build), you should just be able to drag it from the Project explorer onto the form designer

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry i didnt get it, do u mean that i ahve to add the jpanel class to netbeans and then draw it to the designer?..another question please, is there any wayin the designer to specify the image that i ish to add to the jpanel?

Comment: Basically, yes.  Drag the `FacePanel` to what ever form you want it to appear on.  Based on the `FacePanel`, I would say the only way to set the image is via the `setFace` method and I'm pretty sure that the form editor won't pick it up

Comment: @MadProgrammer unfortunately the the designer is not allowing draging the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `class FacePanel extends JPanel {` to `public class FacePanel extends JPanel {`, otherwise Netbeans won't be able to create an instance of it.
2. Do a "Clean and build"
3. Drag the `FacePanel` class from the Project explorer onto your form...

[image: Drag]

Comment: thank you, despite the problem is now solved, i want not to work with netbeans and i want to switch to window builder of eclipse..i read some posts about it and i am abit confused and dont know whther it is free or not? any idea

Comment: No idea, never used Eclipse. You're actually better off learning to hand code you UI's, this way you don't get tied to a single tool and learn the tips and tricks you will need to get any form editor to work well.